# what does this docker command line do

Tags: docker

EDIT: specifically I'm asking should I change /Users/bob to my user name or what happens if I leave it as bob but there is no user bob

I've installed docker on windows 10 with WSL and was told to run this line in command prompt:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 -v /Users/bob/myJupyter:/home/jovyan/work    bob22/data_mining1
```

I know -p is the port number for jupyter and -v is volume but what does everything after `-v` do?

let's say my windows user name is dave but I ran the above command as is with `Users/bob/...`

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/

Comment: If you've read through the documentation for the `docker run` command and you've found something unclear, let us know specifically what you're unsure about and we can probably help out.

Comment: See also https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only

Comment: I see I wasn't specific enough. Specifically I'm asking should I change /Users/bob to my user name or what happens if I leave it as bob but there is no user bob

Answer (score 1):

`-p` is short for `--publish`, which is the port as you state (port `8888` on the host maps to port `8888` inside the container).

`-v` is short for `--volume`, which maps a host path to the container path, so in your case `/Users/bob/myJupyter` on your host will map to `/home/jovyan/work` inside the container.

The last part `bob22/data_mining1` is the name of the image to use for the container, which may be pulled from a repository (like docker-hub) if not found on your local machine already.

Since I don't see `bob22/data_mining1` on docker-hub, I suspect they expect you to create an image on your local machine first (or perhaps pull from another repository).

Comment: I should have mentioned I changed the name for privacy but the repository does exist and it downloaded. And I guess I wasn't specific enough. I was asking if I should be changing `/Users/bob` to my user name and what happens if I leave it as bob but there is no user bob

Comment: Most likely you'll want to update the `/Users/bob` to whatever is relevant on your machine.